# AntiXSS in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, xss, antiforgerytoken

Experimenting AntiXSS in ServiceStack.  I saw you have lots of work put into AntiXsrf namespace.  I added token in form, tried AntiForgery.Validate using global and request filter, all seem work fine.

Also, if I use request filter, is there a way to decorate auth/credential?  Since I also has a CustomAuthProvider, I can authService.RequestContext.Get() and run validate separately if necessary.

Just want to verify this is the right approach, or in case you already have something built in that I missed.

BTW, is stackoverflow the preferred place to ask all these amateurish questions ^_^ ?  Or should I ask more often in the google groups?